# count overlap between two numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let's say I have two arrays a and b:

```
a = np.arange(0,100).reshape(10,2,5)
b = np.arange(50,500).reshape(45,2,5)
```

I need to know how many of the 10 arrays in `a` arrays are in  `b`. The following function does the job but it's not efficient enough:

```
def measure_overlap(array_1, array_2):
    co = 0
    for i in range(0, len(array_1)):
        if array_1[i] in array_2:
            co = co + 1
    return co

measure_overlap(a, b)
5
```

Comment: Do you mean "10 2 dimensional arrays"?

Comment: Thank's for that.. actually it doesn't matter which shape it is, I've just removed it..

Comment: No problem. Fair enough.

Comment: Looks like I found the duplicate while working out a solution.

Comment: no it's not the correct answer. I've edited the question as a and b can also be of different shapes.. can you reopen the question?

Comment: Sure it is. Imagine running it on `a = a.reshape(10, -1)` and it'll be the same.

Comment: Basically turn each of the sub-arrays into 1-D arrays containing all the data you are comparing and it becomes identical. That's what the -1 argument to `reshape` does. A more general phrasing is probably `a = a.reshape(a.shape[0], -1)`

Comment: great, it does the job very efficient; thanks!